# Using Mapbox GL JS 2.x offline, using self hosted tiles

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, openmaptiles

Is it possible to use Mapbox GL JS 2.x completely offline, with self-hosted tiles (e.g. [openmaptiles](https://openmaptiles.org/))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to use Mapbox GL JS offline - received answer from mapbox support:

> Thanks for reaching out! Mapbox GL JS doesn't have a concept of
> offline mode at this time. An internet connection is required. We do
> have offline functionality available with our mobile SDKs. You can
> check out the offline options here -
> https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/mobile-offline/

Comment: Oh, this is bad! will it be possible?

Comment: @BastianonMassimo you have to downgrade Mapbox GL to version 1.13.0, which still supports offline usage. Or use one of Mapbox GL 1.x forks (like https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js)

Comment: @Wolkenarchitekt I hope by now MapLibre has became "the fork", with a lot of participation from the community and large corporations alike :)